# Group Initiative

Tags: pathfinder-1e, house-rules, initiative

Is there a way I could have the entire group roll initiative, add up their score, and do the same for the monsters. adding or subtracting to the amount of rolls depending on the number of creatures attacking the group? The group with the higher score would go first. I ask because I want to have all the players be interacting in combat and be working together, to make combat fast paced and decrease boredom.

I want to know if using this system would increase the pace of combat, to the sort of system fitting for a Dark Souls-esque campaign.

Comment: It's unclear what you need help with here exactly. It sounds like you've just described a viable method to us, then asked us if you can do it. Are you looking for an initiative system that sticks to each side just going at once? If so, what features do you want from it?

Comment: It won't necessarily make combat faster when you give PCs more choices. I've seen roll-each-round go faster than D&D 3E+ and Pathfinder's default, despite all the extra dice rolls, simply because less can be planned.

Comment: @NeilSlater, I actually have my players re-roll on each round. To my point of view it adds a lot of spice because you never know whether the monsters or the players are first/last...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do that exactly as you described, if you wanted.  Maybe have the side with fewer people have everyone roll, and the side with more people only the top X roll, where X is the number on the other side.  (ex 4 players vs. 7 bandits, only the four fastest bandits would roll against the players; 4 players vs. 1 boss monsters, only the fastest player would roll against the monster).

Other methods:

- **[Popcorn Initiative](https://theangrygm.com/popcorn-initiative-a-great-way-to-adjust-dd-and-pathfinder-initiative-with-a-stupid-name/)**, where the current player chooses who goes after him, but no one can go twice until everyone has gone.  This lets the players set up interesting tactics and take risks or play conservatively - if every player goes first, then every enemy will get to go, and the last enemy gets to choose who starts the next round...  meaning every enemy could go twice before the players get another turn!
- **Fastest Man** - roll initiative normally, whichever side has the highest single roll amongst them goes first.  Note this makes big groups faster on average, which is a little counter-intuitive, but PC teams typically have that one guy who goes first, so this *could* favor the PCs even when they're outnumbered.
- **Weakest Link** - roll initiative normally, whichever side has the lowest roll goes second.  Note this will make one poor roller in a party get glares from the rest of the group, but it makes big groups slower.
- **Fastest Man, Solo edition** - the person on each side with the highest initiative modifier rolls it, instead of everyone on the team.
- **Fastest Man, Falco edition** - As Solo edition, but each team's roller gets a +1 for each teammate they have.
- **Surprise Is Speed** - no more surprise rounds, if either side wins surprise, they go first.  If neither side wins surprise, determine using another method.
- **Surprise is King** - As Surprise Is Speed, but keep surprise rounds - this means ambushers will get two turns before their hapless foes every time.
- **Average Initiative** - average the init scores of each side, roll once using the average as the modifier.
- **Very Average Initiative** - average the init scores of each side, don't roll anything, higher init goes first.

This aren't necessarily in order by most recommended to least recommended, just giving you options.  Popcorn Initiative is my favorite, though.

---

**In regards to speed of combat:**  Popcorn Initiative makes my fights run a little faster, but it's not a big change and might not be the same with every group - not having to nitpick to manipulate the initiative order helps my group, but the additional strategic choices might slow a different group down.  Single roll styles speed up the actual "determining who goes first" part, but having the team move together gives them each a LOT more choices in determining what to do, so I find it typically actually goes slower.

You might consider asking as a separate question (or just searching for, I'm certain someone's asked at some point) about ways to increase the pace of combat.  Not sure messing with initiative is going to make it much faster.

Comment: One more, which I usually like: Only one of each group rolls, but gets +1 for everyone on his team. So the fastest Man gives your team High initiative, but a large group still has the upper hand... (Bigger groups having someone who goes before the group is expected, since the chance of one rolling a 20 increases, so it is somewhat ok)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could, just you suggest or as others have suggested, but not without messing up the combat system.

Combat is turn based, so each of your players still has to decide what he does and when it is your PC's turn they still have to decide (or roll) in which order they will act. When the players act they still have to roll attack and damage rolls. So little is gained except for the first set of initiative rolls.

**Combat becomes much more volatile**. Suppose the monster get to go first. They could for example all team up on one of your players (and when he is dead go on to the next). There is nothing your players can do about that until it is their turn. When the turns of the players and monsters are mixed, other players can help a player that is under serious threat by attacking the attackers, healing, buffing, ... So in a sense they are less working together than before. And the other way around when you players go first, encounters can become much less difficult, as they can all team up in the first round on the strongest opponent.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way of doing group initiative in early editions of D&D was to simply roll an (unmodified) d6 each round for each side and the high roll goes first.